# perl warning for MakeFile.PL Both ABSTRACT_FROM and ABSTRACT are set. Ignoring ABSTRACT_FROM

Tags: perl, makefile

I am making Make.PL file which is throwing the following warning while running the `MakeFile.PL`.

`Both ABSTRACT_FROM and ABSTRACT are set.  Ignoring ABSTRACT_FROM.`

here is the code of my Make.PL

```
     use strict;
     use warnings FATAL => 'all';
     use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

     WriteMakefile(
          NAME             => 'Foo',
          AUTHOR           => q{abc <abc.email.com>},
          VERSION_FROM     => 'lib/Foo.pm',
          ABSTRACT         => 'Foo.pm',
          ABSTRACT_FROM    => 'Foo.pm',
          LICENSE          => 'Artistic_2_0',
          PL_FILES         => {},
          MIN_PERL_VERSION => 5.006,
          CONFIGURE_REQUIRES => {
                                   'ExtUtils::MakeMaker' => 0,
                                },
          BUILD_REQUIRES => {

               #s'FASTAParse'   => 0.0.3,
              'Test::More'   => 0,
              'Test::Simple' => 0,
              },

         PREREQ_PM => {
                'FASTAParse'   => 0.0.3,
         },
         dist  => { COMPRESS => 'gzip -9f', SUFFIX => 'gz', },
         clean => { FILES => 'NUCSurf-*' },

        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove one of the variables or ignore the warning.

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

Remove the ABSTRACT line.

https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#ABSTRACT:

> ABSTRACT
>
> One line description of the module. Will be included in PPD file.
>
> ABSTRACT_FROM
>
> Name of the file that contains the package description. MakeMaker looks for a line in the POD matching /^($package\s-\s)(.*)/. This is typically the first line in the "=head1 NAME" section. $2 becomes the abstract.

What you are specifying belongs in ABSTRACT_FROM, not ABSTRACT.

Though I believe you want 'lib/Foo.pm' there, not just 'Foo.pm'.